# How to randomly add children of nodes from Array onto the parent node?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I wonder how to implement the function that adds nodes randomly from the top of the screen. So I need various colors of nodes, and I put them into an array. Then random number is made. In total, there are five nodes in the array, and I set the number to 5.

```
func fallingObjects(){

    let randomWidth = arc4random_uniform(60)
    let randomHeight = arc4random_uniform(60)

    let node1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(randomWidth), CGFloat(randomHeight)))
    let node2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(randomWidth), CGFloat(randomHeight)))
    let node3 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.brownColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(randomWidth), CGFloat(randomHeight)))
    let node4 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.lightGrayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(randomWidth), CGFloat(randomHeight)))
    let node5 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(randomWidth), CGFloat(randomHeight)))

    var array = [SKSpriteNode]()
    array.append(node1)
    array.append(node2)
    array.append(node3)
    array.append(node4)
    array.append(node5)

    let ranNum = arc4random_uniform(5)
    for a in array {
        addChild(a[ranNum])
    }
}
```

I know that I am doing wrong but it is appreciated if you point out the problem. And give me solution :)

Comment: You should probably just create a random node when you need it as you can only add a given instance node once

Comment: Could you show me sample code? It is much more helpful!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's hard to tell by reading the code. (For example, you're accessing `a[ranNum]`, but `a` is a SKSpriteNode there.)

Comment: Since I am not really sure of how to implement code I want to write, the code I wrote up there is a bit weird. The idea is that I want to create many nodes of various colors and all of them fall down to the Y point, 0 at a different time. And I want this function to repeat forever until a node that I control gets collided with one of them.